# Styling element table only table with specific class

Tags: html, css

In my page, I have many table. Every table has different style. One table I want give style like this `table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 10px }`

If I use this, all of them will effected.

how I achieve this if I only one table to styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different classes for different tables

```
<table class = "first-table"> </table>
```

and then select them by

```
.first-table {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 10px;
}
```

If you don't want to use classes, you can use selectors like

```
tr > td {}
```

But selecting children from a parent element can get quite tricky at times, in the end is all depends on you, hope it helps

Comment: how i styling the child of <td> and <th> of table that has class first-table?

Comment: well if it is a child of td and th both then you can use:  td th .first-table {       }